# iOS Practice for using cocoapod and source control

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Currently, in our company, we just commit all pods (like AFNetworking, Realm, etc) to svn/git. From time to time, when other developer install pod, update pod, there are conflict.

We also use this so that we don't touch other pods.

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

Can I know what is the good practice for using third party pods? Do I need to commit those pods?

Or just do pod install again after our codes are checked out ? I just want to avoid code conflict for using pods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-ignore-the-pods-directory-in-source-control

Whether you check in or not, the Pods directory, the Podfile and Podfile.lock should always be kept under version control. It is recommended to keep it under version control and **don't add it to your .gitignore**

Comment: Thanks. I will read through that guide first. I might need to summarize after reading.

Answer (score 1):

We also faced the same problem.As a solution, in commit we write only pod file with required pod list . Whenever other person take update, his podfile is updated and then from console he update his project pods.

As pod is same for all so you dont need to commit the pods. for more specific you can you can give pod with version.

Comment: Thanks. I will take note of that.

Answer (score 1):

Khant usually it's not a good practice to upload your dependencies to your repositories mostly because your will be saving space and time. it's ok to push your Podfile but all the code of your dependencies should be omitted and installed locally for each developer. And each time a new dependency is added or update you will just need to run the `pod update` command. to do that you can add to your .gitignore file on a new line just `Pods/`.
Either way if you are working on a big scale application you should on swift you should follow the best practices and use a correctly .gitignore setup like this one [example](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore) and also if you want to know some pros and cons on avoiding Cocoapods dependencies you can check this [official documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we don't push all pods to svn or git. You can commit only Podfile and may want to freeze to a specific version of a Pod, in which case you can specify that version number.

pod 'Objection', '0.9'

And when other members install pods, it will be same.

Comment: Thanks. i will take note of putting specific version.